# Convert a vector logo into a Monochrome Bitmap in illustrator

Tags: vector, color-conversion, monochrome, file-conversion

I have designed a logo in illustrator CC 2014 and it's dimensions are 128px x 32px [image]

which I want to convert into a **Monochrome Bitmap picture**.
I have tried the solution from this [forum](http://www.graphicdesignforum.com/forum/forum/graphic-design/general/46639-monochrome-in-illustrator). Still blurred image.
I also tried using **Microsoft Paint** but still the quality is deteriorated as shown below.

How do I convert the vector image of dimensions 128px x 32px into a Monochrome Bitmap without losing the quality?
Please help.

Comment: You probably need a bit more info than this because as the question is now its totally unanswerable

Comment: The issue is converting that 128x32 vector image into a monochrome bitmap image without losing the clarity of the logo. @joojaa

Comment: Yes but what does the logo look like before conversion how on earth do we advice if we only see whats broken.

Comment: Basic steps.. convert to 1 color and size properly in Illustrator, using the vector data. Save. Open in Photoshop. Convert to BMP. Save . . .

Comment: @Scott I don't understand what you mean by "using vector data". Please expound.

Comment: I mean change color and size **in Illustrator** -- this assumes the logo is already vector in Illustrator. If it's raster.. then there's no point to using Illustrator at all. And *that* logo at 32px high is going to just be a spot with some dark center shape. It's not going to hold up at that small of a size.

Comment: @Scott Okay, I will do just that, save it in a vector form (.AI) then do the rest and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is an illustrator (vector) file, reduce it's size to 32px high and alter the color so everything is either black or white (no grays).

Save the file as an Illustrator file once you have done the above.

Then open the Illustrator file with Photoshop and *rasterize* it. Note, simply opening it should rasterize it, if by chance it opens as a smart object, then merge it with a blank layer to rasterize it or use the contextual menu to rasterize the smart object layer.

This should result in an RGB 33x32px image. (or roughly that size)

Use `Image > Mode > Greyscale` to remove the color data from the image.

Use `Image > Canvas Size` to set the canvas to 128px wide.

Use `Image > Mode > Bitmap` to convert the file to bmp format. If you want the *size* of the image to remain the same, then you need the output to match the input - so 72PPi -- this is a VERY low resolution for a bmp image. This isn't going to reproduce wonderfully in print. But in print you'd probably not use a BMP image anyway. You have *not* described *why* you need the BMP format.

The result is a black circle with some blob in the middle, see below (minus the pink).

[image]

(Edges could be a tad smoother, but that is going to require you to *manually* use a small brush, like 1px in diameter, and go in and add or remove individual pixels to better define areas. The BMP format does not allow "grey" pixels so you won't get any anti-aliasing.)

If your desire is a clearly identifiable one color logo, the logo needs to be reworked to meet this size. It is simply *not a good logo* for one color at this size.

Comment: it's even worse. Take a look. https://ngeshdesign.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/bitmap2.png.

Comment: The steps I provided above resulted in the image I posted and I **started with the low resolution web image** you posted here. If I had started with a vector file, the results would be even better. I don't know how you are getting such poor results.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to create icons of the image. Vector are not pixels however if you want to achieve this below, here it is.

128px

[image: 128px]

32px

[image: 32px]

128x32 is not possible with many loss because it is a square, a circle with same proportions inside a square.